# Android - logs access

Tags: android, security, logging

I have read a couple of times, that some applications on our phone can contain in logs information about eg: call history. I want to write an application which gets to this logs and uses this information. But the question is how can i do that? Logcat - the Android logging system provides a mechanism for collecting and viewing system debug output, so it's not what I am looking for I think. Maybe you can suggest my, how can I get information straight from  logs?

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is not in common log files but in so-called [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Example:

```
static public List<String> getMissedCalls(Context context)
    {
            final String queryCond = Calls.TYPE + " = " + Calls.MISSED_TYPE + " and " + Calls.NEW + " = 1";

            List<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
            Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(
                            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                            new String[]{Calls._ID, Calls.NUMBER},
                            queryCond,
                            null,
                            null
                            );
            //int count=cur.getCount(); 
            //Log.d(TAG, "missed calls = " + count);
            while(cur.moveToNext())
            {
                    String phoneNumber = cur.getString(cur
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(Calls.NUMBER));
                    //Log.d(TAG, "missed call = " + phoneNumber);
                    phoneNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
            }
            cur.close();
            return phoneNumbers;
    }
```